# Rewrite with if and else

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, if-statement, url-rewriting

i have to add if and else to my rewrite rule.

My rewrite is this

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?cat=(.*)&q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q_%2_cat_%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q_(.*)_cat_(.*)?$ /index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,P,NC]
```

and i would like to change to this if cat is in null

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?cat=&q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q_%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q_(.*)$ /index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the two rules one after the other and instead of using `.*`, use `.+`. Also, you don't need the `P` flag, instead use the `L` flag to end rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?cat=(.+)&q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q_%2_cat_%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q_(.+)_cat_(.+)$ /index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?cat=&q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q_%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q_([^_]+)$ /index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Greaaaaat!... thanks... after 3 o 4 hours i'm working for that you solved in 5 minuts... Thanks aloooot!!!